# Can't write a dialog system for unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to write a script for a dialog system. Naturally, I used a manual from the Internet, but I also tried to do something myself. I finished it, but there is one problem. When I tested the script on one object, it worked as it should, but when I added a second object, it stopped working. More specifically, the dialog box itself doesn't appear. I hear the letter output sound, but the dialog box doesn't appear. Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using System.Collections;

public class DialogueSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject dialogueBox;
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI dialogueText;
    [SerializeField] string[] lines;
    [SerializeField] AudioSource printSFX;
    [SerializeField] float printTime = 0.1f;
    private int index;
    public bool playerNearby;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        dialogueText.text = string.Empty;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && playerNearby)
        {
            if(dialogueBox.activeInHierarchy)
                CloseDialogue();
            else
                StartDialogue();
        } 
        if(dialogueText.text == lines[index] && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
            NextLine();
        if(!playerNearby)
            CloseDialogue();
    }

    private void StartDialogue()
    {
        dialogueBox.SetActive(true);
        index = 0;
        StartCoroutine(PrintLine());
    }

    IEnumerator PrintLine()
    {
        foreach(char letter in lines[index].ToCharArray())
        {
            dialogueText.text += letter;
            printSFX.Play();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(printTime);
        }
    }

    private void NextLine()
    {
        if (index < lines.Length-1) 
        {
            index++;
            dialogueText.text = string.Empty;
            StartCoroutine(PrintLine());
        } else
        {
            CloseDialogue();
        }
    }

    public void CloseDialogue()
    {
        dialogueText.text = string.Empty;
        index = 0;
        dialogueBox.SetActive(false) ;
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerNearby = true;
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerNearby = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same dialogueBox reference for all instances?   If so, the problem is likely `if(!playerNearby) CloseDialogue();`, each script that is far from the player will constantly be closing the dialog box.  Instead of checking in update, why not close it when the trigger happens

Answer (score 0):

The solution is bad, but it works, and that's what matters to me. I decided to try to create a Frankenstein: I took the part of the code that was responsible for dealing damage to players and adapted it to my situation. In fact, the code has not changed much, only the StartDialogue method has changed

```
    public void StartDialogue()
{
    dialogueBox.SetActive(true);
    Collider2D[] obtainedDialogues = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(dialoguePoint.position, dialogueRange, npcLayer);

    foreach (Collider2D dialogues in obtainedDialogues)
        obtainedText = dialogues.GetComponent<DialogueHolder>().GiveText();

    StartCoroutine(PrintLine());
}
```

I also added an additional check in the Update method. I don't know why, but nothing works without it

```
index < obtainedText.Length
```